# Getting ping from remote server in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot with discord.py for my personal server. My friend and I are frequent gamers, and love playing League of Legends, so I figured a cool functionality for our bot would be to display our current latency between us and Riot's servers. So far, I have this attached code, but this always returns the ping from where the bot is hosted. Is there a way for me to get the ping of the person who issues the command to the bot? Code uses pythonping, found here https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/. Thanks :)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pythonping import ping

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command()
    async def lolping(ctx):
    server = '104.160.131.3'
    response = ping(server, size=40, count = 10)
    print(response)
    await ctx.send(f'Current NA LOL Ping: {response.rtt_avg_ms}ms')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The reason it always returns the bot's ping is because the bot initiates the ping request. The command just tells the bot to do it.

The bot cannot start a ping request from another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Benjin's answer ...

As per the definition of [a ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)), the machine sending the ping (in this case the discord bot) measures the time it takes to receive its packet back. Therefore, as the bot cannot send a packet from the user's machine, it is impossible for it to measure their ping.

Perhaps you could have the bot provide a link to Riot's lag-report page [here](https://lagreport.na.leagueoflegends.com) so that users can check themselves based on their locations. However, this seems to only work for certain locations and I don't know how useful it is.

Good Luck!